# Fill a table variable using CTE

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I am creating a CTE as I need all InquiryId in a variable in order to proceed to a WHILE loop.
I am trying to fill a variable via a CTE like below

```
DECLARE @inqIdsToClose TABLE (InquiryId int)
With CTE (InquiryId,InquirySubject,CreateDt,SendTo,[From],SendBy) as
(
    Select I.InquiryId,I.InquirySubject,I.CreateDt,I.SendTo,I.[From],U.Email as SendBy
    From Inquiries I
    Inner Join Users U
    ON I.[From] = U.UserID
    Where I.InquiryId Not In (Select InquiryId from InquiryReply)
    And I.InquiryStatusId  <> 5
    And DATEDIFF(day, I.CreateDt, getdate()) >=7
)
Insert into @inqIdsToClose
Select InquiryId from CTE
Print @inqIdsToClose;
```

But SQL Server is not allowing me to fill @inqIdsToClose

The InquiryId which are returned by CTE are multiple which I will later use in a while loop.

Comment: Just making sure `I.InquiryID` really is an `Int`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yes it is. It's a non nullable int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing the terminator after you declared your table variable

**Example**

```
DECLARE @inqIdsToClose TABLE (InquiryId int);

with cte as (
    -- Dummy query
    Select SomeVal=1
    Union All
    Select SomeVal=2
)
Insert Into @inqIdsToClose Select SomeVal from cte

Select * from @inqIdsToClose
```

**Returns**

```
InquiryId
1
2
```

Comment: @Rishabh Don't beat yourself up over that.  I can't count the number of hours looking something and it was a semicolon or lowercase variable  :)

Comment: Now I am trying to perform a While loop on this variable. Is it possible ?

Comment: @Rishabh A table variable acts like a table, but there are scope issues.  One the thread is done, it evaporates.   Rather than a loop, would a CROSS APPLY work?   I try to avoid loops when possible

Comment: @Rishabh Rather than a table variable, you always have the option of a temp table.

Comment: Agreed. I think i can create a separate procedure to pass in inquiryid in it and then use it as required rather than doing everything in the same proc

Comment: @Rishabh The fun part is creating the solution :)